# Analytic Branch of Cubed Root of a function

Tags: complex-analysis

This is an old preliminary exam problem: Show that there exists an analytic function $g(z)$ on $\Omega=\mathbb{C}\backslash[0,2]$ such that $g(z)^3=z(z-1)(z-2)$

I'm not sure exactly what to say beyond the fact that the function $z(z-1)(z-2)$ is nonzero on $\Omega$ and so there is a branch of $h(z):=\frac{1}{3}log(z(z-1)(z-2))$ defined there. Then $\exp(3h(z))$ is analytic because it is the composition of analytic functions. Is this all that there is to it, or is there more to be done here?

For example, is it necessary to actually compute a taylor series for $g(z)$? How would this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is that $\Omega$ is not simply connected, so it does not automatically follow that a nonzero analytic function has an analytic logarithm (or an analytic cube root) there.

You might start with $z(z-1)(z-2) = z^3 f(z)$ where $f(z) =(1-1/z)(1-2/z)$, and show this has an analytic cube root near $\infty$.

Comment: To justify that $f$ has an analytic cubed root of infinity, can I apply the map $\phi: z\mapsto \frac{1}{z}$? Then we obtain a simply connected region $\phi(\Omega)=\mathbb{C}\backslash [0,\infty]$ where $f(1/z)$ is nonzero? Also, is there a way to do this using the binomial therem to expand $(1-z)^{1/3}(2-z)^{1/3}$?

Answer (score 2):

If what you said was correct then it would be all you need to do, but it's not: just because $z(z-1)(z-2)$ is nonzero on $\Omega$ doesn't mean that there is a branch of $\log(z(z-1)(z-2))$ defined there.  It is true that if $f(z)$ is analytic and nonzero on a *simply connected* domain $\Omega$, then there is an analytic branch of $\log f(z)$ on $\Omega$, but your $\Omega$ is not simply connected.

Since $\Omega$ is not simply connected, you need to consider what happens when you go around a non-contractible loop.  The fundamental group of $\Omega$ is generated by a loop $\gamma$ that goes around $[0,2]$ counterclockwise.  As you analytically continue $\log(z(z-1)(z-2))$ around the loop $\gamma$, $\log(z(z-1)(z-2))=\log z+\log(z-1)+\log(z-2)$ will increase by $6\pi i$, since $\gamma$ has winding number $1$ around each of $0$, $1$, and $2$, so each term increases by $2\pi i$.  So $\frac{1}{3}\log(z(z-1)(z-2))$ increases by $2\pi i$ as you go around $\gamma$, which means $\exp(\frac{1}{3}\log(z(z-1)(z-2)))$ is well-defined.

More explicitly, you could choose a branch $a(z)$ of $z^{1/3}$ on $\mathbb{C}\setminus [0,\infty)$ and another branch $b(z)$ of $z^{1/3}$ on $\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]$ such that $a(z)=b(z)$ on the lower half plane and $a(z)=e^{2\pi i/3} b(z)$ on the upper half plane.  Then take $g_0(z)=a(z)a(z-1)a(z-2)$ and $g_1(z)=b(z)b(z-1)b(z-2)$.  Notice that either $g_0$ or $g_1$ is defined in a neighborhood of every point of $\Omega$, and $g_0$ and $g_1$ agree on the intersection of their domains (since on the upper half plane they differ by a factor of $e^{2\pi i/3}\cdot e^{2\pi i/3}\cdot e^{2\pi i/3}=1$).  So $g_0$ and $g_1$ glue together to give a function $g(z)$ which is analytic on all of $\Omega$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trick for solving some of these problems with polynomials, based on the following basic property. If $z_0, z_1$ are in the same connected component of the complement of a domain $D$, then there exists an analytic $f$ on $D$ such that $e^{f(z)} = \frac{z-z_0}{z-z_1}$; see below for a proof, or any of a variety of textbooks, like Narasimhan. To use it to solve your problem, note that since $0$ and $2$ are in the same connected component of $(\mathbb{C}\backslash [0,2])^c$, our lemma shows there exists an analytic $f_0$ such that $e^{f_0(z)} = \frac{z}{z-2}$. Likewise, there exists an analytic $f_1$ such that $e^{f_1(z)} = \frac{z}{z-z_1}$. Therefore
\begin{align*}
z(z-1)(z-2) = \frac{z}{z-2} \cdot\frac{z-1}{z-2} \cdot (z-2)^3 = \left(e^{\frac{f_0(z)}{3}} e^{\frac{f_1(z)}{3}} (z - 2)\right)^3.
\end{align*}
And so we see that $e^{\frac{f_0(z)}{3}} e^{\frac{f_1(z)}{3}} (z - 2)$ is an analytic cube root of $z(z-1)(z-2)$ on $\mathbb{C}\backslash[0, 2]$.

(The middle paragraph in Eric Wofsey's answer seems to be the way Gamelin intends this kind of question to be answered though, based on the hint to exercise 4 from section VIII.6.)

---

#### Proof of basic property, $e^{f(z)} = \frac{z - z_0}{z - z_1}$

Consider a closed curve $\gamma$ in a domain $D$, and let $g(z) = \frac{z-z_0}{z - z_1}$.
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{g'}{g} dz = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{1}{z - z_0} - \frac{1}{z - z_1} dz = W(\gamma, z_0) - W(\gamma, z_1) = 0.
\end{align*}
$W(\gamma, z_0)$ denotes the winding number of $\gamma$ around $z_0$, and is defined to be $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z - z_0}.$ The last equality follows because $z_0$ and $z_1$ are in the same connected component of the complement of $\gamma$, and using a basic fact about winding numbers, this implies $W(\gamma, z_0) = W(\gamma, z_1)$.

Since this equality holds for all $\gamma$, $\frac{g'}{g}dz$ has the path independence property, which implies there exists an analytic $h$ on $D$ such that $h' = \frac{g'}{g}$. (Define $h(z)$ by integrating $\frac{g'}{g}$ along any path from some $a$ to $z$.) This means $h$ is an analytic branch of $\log(g(z))$ on $D$. Finally, there's the following standard trick to show $e^{h(z)} = g(z)$,

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial z} g(z) e^{-h(z)} = g'(z) e^{-h(z)} - g(z) h'(z) e^{-h(z)} = g'(z) e^{-h(z)} - g(z) \left(\frac{g'(z)}{g(z)}\right)e^{-h(z)} = 0.
\end{align*}
This means $g(z) e^{-h(z)} = C(z)$, where $C(z)$ is locally constant on $D$. So $g(z) = e^{h(z) + \log(C(z))}$, where $\log(C(z))$ is constant on each connected component of $D$, implying that $f(z) := h(z) + \log(C(z))$ is analytic on $D$.

See Gamelin for background on these concepts.